# MySQL query for search by set of space separated values

Tags: mysql

I've got a sample table:

```
Firstname Lastname Company  Age
Peter     Johnson  Google   28
John      Wayne    Yahoo    30
```

I need to write a MySQL query which performs search through set of values separated by space. Like this:

```
Exec find_records 'Bill Johnson Google 30';
```

Query should return:

```
Firstname Lastname  Company  Age
Peter     Johnson   Google
John      Wayne     Yahoo
```

Will appreciate any ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a MyISAM table you could add a fulltext index on the columns relevant to the search and query with:

```
SELECT
  firstname,
  lastname,
  company,
  age,
  MATCH(firstname, lastname, company, age) AGAINST('Bill Johnson Google 30') as rank
FROM
  your_table
HAVING
  rank > 0
ORDER BY
  rank DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/044f9/6)

```
select *
from t
where 
FIND_IN_SET(FirstName,REPLACE('Bill Johnson Google 30',' ',','))>0
or
FIND_IN_SET(Lastname,REPLACE('Bill Johnson Google 30',' ',','))>0
or
FIND_IN_SET(Company,REPLACE('Bill Johnson Google 30',' ',','))>0
or 
FIND_IN_SET(Age,REPLACE('Bill Johnson Google 30',' ',','))>0
```